# How to build a FreeBSD chroot inside of Linux

Tags: linux, freebsd

Is it possible to build a chroot environment which is running FreeBSD inside of Linux, if so, how would I go about build a chroot environment from within Linux?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "FreeBSD chroot environment". Do you mean a chroot environment which is running FreeBSD, or an environment set up using some FreeBSD implementation of chroot on Linux?

Comment: I would like to have a working or semi-working FreeBSD environment inside that chroot on Linux.

Comment: It seems you may want to run FreeBSD in a virtual machine. I doubt the base system of FreeBSD would compile cleanly on top of Linux...

Comment: Compiling aside, isn't there something like a base jail or chroot image that I could download then extract like gentoo's stage3?  Then, with that, couldn't I merely do the normal mounts and get it working?  FreeBSD ships with binary packages, so I wouldn't need to worry about compiling unless I wanted to.  Also, if I did want to compile, wouldn't I be doing that inside the chroot environment which has all of the necessary libraries at that point?

Comment: `kvm`  and `qemu`  and a virtual machine are the way here, Linux is not Unix. Although they share some concept the implementation is different binary format /kernel and things like that are very unlikely compatible. I would recommand you a VM.

Comment: You would still be running a Linux kernel. Everything would need to be ported and recompiled to be working with Linux system calls instead of FreeBSD system calls. You want a virtual machine.

Comment: Ok, so assuming I setup kvm and qemu, is there a base "image" I can start with?

Comment: @Walter You would be doing a standard FreeBSD installation in the virtual machine. The FreeBSD handbook will have the info: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/

Comment: @Waler There appears to be VMs available for download too: https://www.freebsd.org/where.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

FreeBSD and Linux are two different *kernels* (well, FreeBSD users will argue with me here, but the core of FreeBSD is a different kernel), so you can’t run one on top of the other without some sort of emulation or virtualisation layer.

The easiest way to run FreeBSD on a Linux-based system is to use a virtual machine such as [QEMU](https://www.qemu.org/).

If you’re really keen, you might be able to run a pure FreeBSD chroot on a *distribution* with a familiar set of tools, *e.g.* [Debian GNU/kFreeBSD](https://www.debian.org/ports/kfreebsd-gnu/). You can apparently do the opposite, *i.e.* [run a Debian GNU/kFreeBSD chroot on top of FreeBSD](https://wiki.debian.org/Debian_GNU/kFreeBSD_FAQ#Q._Can_I_run_Debian_GNU.2FkFreeBSD_in_a_chroot_under_FreeBSD.3F). In both cases you’re using the FreeBSD kernel, there’s no Linux kernel involved.