# Are different Linux/Unix kernels interchangeable?

Tags: linux, kernel, bsd, architecture

Can I take a Linux kernel and use it with, say, FreeBSD and vice versa (FreeBSD kernel in, say, a Debian)? Is there a universal answer? What are the limitations? What are the obstructions?

Comment: No, absolutely not. A good exercise would be to try it and see how it breaks. You can't even replace a Linux kernel with a much older Linux kernel reliably. Replacing userland tools is definitely doable though (if recompiled).

Comment: https://www.debian.org/ports/kfreebsd-gnu/ and https://www.debian.org/ports/hurd/ might interest you

Comment: @Kusalananda regarding replacing userland tools, going from BSD to Linux can be painful: some BSD tools are quite hard to build on non-BSD systems... I’ve come across a few tools over the years which I would have liked to port, but it turned out to be non-trivial :-/.

Comment: @StephenKitt The reverse is true too :-) Especially when the software makes assumptions about being able to access `/proc`or other Linux-specific bells and whistles.

Comment: What you can do is to take a x86_64 (linux) kernel and force-install it on i386 32-bit distribution (assuming a 64-bit intel CPU and support for 32-bit binaries compiled in). This is quite well known, but not immediately obvious...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

No, kernels from different implementations of Unix-style operating systems are not interchangeable, notably because they all present different interfaces to the rest of the system (user space) — their system calls (including `ioctl` specifics), the various virtual file systems they use...

What is interchangeable to some extent, at the source level, is the combination of the kernel and the C library, or rather, the user-level APIs that the kernel and libraries expose (essentially, the view at the layer described by POSIX, without considering whether it *is* actually POSIX). Examples of this include [Debian GNU/kFreeBSD](https://www.debian.org/ports/kfreebsd-gnu/), which builds a Debian system on top of a FreeBSD kernel, and [Debian GNU/Hurd](https://www.debian.org/ports/hurd/), which builds a Debian system on top of the Hurd.

This isn’t quite at the level of kernel interchangeability, but there have been attempts to standardise a common application binary interface, to allow binaries to be used on various systems without needing recompilation. One example is [the Intel Binary Compatibility Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Binary_Compatibility_Standard), which allows binaries conforming to it to run on any Unix system implementing it, including older versions of Linux with the iBCS 2 layer. I used this in the late 90s to run WordPerfect on Linux.

See also [How to build a FreeBSD chroot inside of Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/420418/86440).

Comment: Some people have [quite strong opinions](http://www.firstruleofkerneldevelopment.com/) on how important it is to keep the kernel and user APIs synced :)

Comment: Indeed @tonysdg, and believe me, [I know all about that](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=ec8b4b7085605e801a7740a2c3c33256aebe249c) :-/.

Comment: @tonysdg I get a page not found on your link. (Unless that's a joke I'm missing?)

Comment: @mbrig: Until yesterday, it was there -- here's an archived version: https://web.archive.org/web/20171102142621/http://www.firstruleofkerneldevelopment.com/

Comment: @StephenKitt: Ouch :( Sorry!! But major kudos for even having code in the kernel to begin with!

Answer (score 5):

Some kernels have binary compatibility allowing you to mix userspace programs with different ABIs (eg freebsd can work with linux binaries to a degree) - however, the core binaries (eg the init program, the module loader, device driver setup tools, the C library, the tools needed to setup the filesystems... ) will in practice have too much need-to-know about kernel level interfaces to boot a system with a foreign kernel successfully.

Also, filesystems would need to be compatible. 
Also, binary compatibility options would need to be compiled "hard" into the kernel - anything implemented as a kernel module would like fail because you could not run the module loader.

As mentioned, the user environments tend to be somewhat portable if you are willing to recompile - like freebsd-based debian systems, or setting up the netbsd pkgsrc system on linux (absolutely non trivial, but supported and possible!).